# How to configure KVM for Android Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, kvm

No matter how I configure my system, Android Studio shows the "We have detected that your system can run the android emulator in an accelerated performance mode. Linuxed-based systems support virtual machine acceleration through the KVM. Search for install instructions for your particular Linux configuration hat KVM is enabled for faster Android emulator performance."

`egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` gives `8`

`kvm-ok` gives `INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used`

`grep kvm /etc/group` gives `kvm:x:108:currentLoggedInUser`

How should I configure KVM correct on Ubuntu 19.10? And how could I tell if Android Studio is running the VM using KVM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue, but the other way around. To make it work, first make sure you've enabled virtualization in the BIOS and added your username in libvirt.

1. Click cancel on the screen that shows Android KVM 
   [image: image here]
2. Android Studio will offer you to two options. Choose the one "don't start the setup wizard" (not the recommended one), so it will take you to the welcome screen.
3. Start a new project as usual and Android Studio will say couldn't find the SDK.
   [image: similar image description here]
4. Choose the libraries and emulators to download and the rest is the same as usual.